# Why does two Mac computers respond differently to a tkinter event?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, events

I use `if str(event.type) == 'ButtonPress': ....`  and `if str(event.type) == 'ButtonRelease': ....` to determine x1, y1, x2, and y2 positions for drawing a rectangle on a tkinter canvas. That works fine on my Apple laptop with python 3.8.1 and tkinter version 8.6.8. However, on my Apple desktop with python 3.8.7 and tkinter version 8.6.8, the exactly same code doesn't work. `print(str(event.type))` shows that these codes generate `ButtonPress` and `ButtonRelease` for pressing and releasing the left mouse button respectively on the laptop. However, on the desktop it results in `4` and `5`.

If it is caused by two different python versions, I can solve it by updating the oldest version, of course. However, how to deal with this in general if other people would like to run the code on their computer? Can I make my code computer independent?

Comment: You could just add a simplie `or` statement to debug this.

Comment: Sometimes it is so easy to solve a problem. I started to learn Python just one year ago and was so surprised that subversions can differ so much. I couldn't find documentation on it. Many thanks.